# C# How to initialization a variable in class?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

I'm creating a `Billing Address` for `User Shipping` including (First Name, Last Name, Address 1, Address 2...) based on `MVC Music Store project`

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddressAndPayment(FormCollection values)
    {
        var order = new SalesOrderHeader();
        var order1 = new SalesOrderDetail();
        TryUpdateModel(order);
        try
        {
            if (string.Equals(values["PromoCode"], PromoCode, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == false)
            {
                return View(order);
            }
            else
            {
                order.AccountNumber = User.Identity.Name;
                order.OrderDate = DateTime.Now;
                order.Address.AddressLine1 = values["AddressLine1"];
                order.Address.AddressLine2 = values["AddressLine2"];
                order.Address.City = values["City"];

                //Save Order
                BikeDBs.SalesOrderHeaders.Add(order);
                BikeDBs.SaveChanges();
                //Process Order

                var cart = ShoppingCart.GetCart(this.HttpContext);
                cart.CreateOrder(order);
                //cart.CreateOrder(order1);

                return RedirectToAction("Complete", new {id = order.SalesOrderID });
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            //Invalid - redisplay with errors
            return View(order);
        }
```

}

May I have ask a dump question? What will I initial a `order.Address` variable? `Address` is `String` type. I just updated my code following your metioned. I based on MVC Music Store project and created a new app using AdventureWork2012 DB.
Here is `View`:

```
<h2>Address And Payment</h2>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Shipping Information</legend>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Customer.Person.FirstName): @Html.TextBox("FirstName") <br />
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Customer.Person.LastName):  @Html.TextBox("LastName") <br />
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Address.AddressLine1): @Html.TextBox("AddressLine1") <br />
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Address.AddressLine2): @Html.TextBox("AddressLine2") <br />
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Address.City): @Html.TextBox("City") <br />
       </fieldset>
```

And a `Address.cs`:

```
public partial class Address
    {
        public Address()
        {
            this.SalesOrderHeaders = new HashSet<SalesOrderHeader>();
            this.SalesOrderHeaders1 = new HashSet<SalesOrderHeader>();
        }

        public int AddressID { get; set; }
        public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }
        public string AddressLine2 { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public int StateProvinceID { get; set; }
        public string PostalCode { get; set; }
        public System.Guid rowguid { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }

        public virtual StateProvince StateProvince { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<SalesOrderHeader> SalesOrderHeaders { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<SalesOrderHeader> SalesOrderHeaders1 { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: You use `string.Empty` for a blank string. Depends on what you want it to contain!

Comment: Or `User.Identity.Address`?

Comment: What do you want it to be ? if u dont need it skip it or set it to empty.

Comment: I want `Address` contains information of Address of User filled in Billing Address form, a `string` type!

Comment: @Baldrick: It throws an error: "Represents the empty string. This field is read only"

Comment: before setting addressline1 try

order.address = new address

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C# `string` will always be `null` if not initialized.

In the [MVC Music Store project](http://mvcmusicstore.codeplex.com), you can follow up the code:

The [AddressAndPayment View](https://mvcmusicstore.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#MvcMusicStore/Views/Checkout/AddressAndPayment.cshtml) shows that the Shipping information has a helper `@Html.EditorForModel()` and the View Model is of the type `MvcMusicStore.Models.Order`.

following up that [class name](https://mvcmusicstore.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#MvcMusicStore/Models/Order.cs) you will see all properties that will be exposed in that form.

and one of those properties is in fact an `Address` written as

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Address is required")]
[StringLength(70)]
public string Address { get; set; }
```

as your `Action` is accepting a `FormCollection` instead of the Model, you will need to do:

```
order.Address = values["Address"];
```

---

**UPDATED** from new code on the question

There's 3 small mistakes with your code:

**1 -** The code is using `TryUpdateModel` and you can't use that with complex types (your new `Address` object is now a complex object and not a primitive one (string, int, etc))

**2 -** Because of the point 1, you need to comment out the `TryUpdateModel` and instead, pass the order as your input like `public ActionResult AddressAndPayment(Order order, FormCollection values)`

**3 -** In your view, you are rendering the new properties with `@Html.TextBox("AddressLine1")` so you are explicit the name of the `<input>` as `AddressLine1` witch it's wrong from your model, it should be `Address.AddressLine1`.

to fix this, use the helper `EditorFor` and use it like:

```
@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Customer.Person.FirstName): 
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Customer.Person.FirstName) <br />

@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Customer.Person.LastName):  
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Customer.Person.LastName) <br />

@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Address.AddressLine1): 
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Address.AddressLine1) <br />

@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Address.AddressLine2): 
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Address.AddressLine2) <br />

@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Address.City): 
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Address.City) <br />
```

This will create an `<input>` like

```
<input class="text-box single-line" id="Address_AddressLine1" name="Address.AddressLine1" type="text" value="">
```

instead the one you currently have:

```
<input id="AddressLine1" name="AddressLine1" type="text">
```

Now, the default Action, will work out of the box, without need to be updated, as when you save the order, it will already have all fields from the form in the `order` object

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddressAndPayment(Order order, FormCollection values)
    {
        try
        {
            if (string.Equals(values["PromoCode"], PromoCode,
                StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == false)
            {
                return View(order);
            }
            else
            {
                order.Username = User.Identity.Name;
                order.OrderDate = DateTime.Now;

                //Save Order
                storeDB.Orders.Add(order);
                storeDB.SaveChanges();

                //Process the order
                var cart = ShoppingCart.GetCart(this.HttpContext);
                cart.CreateOrder(order);

                return RedirectToAction("Complete",
                    new { id = order.OrderId });
            }

        }
        catch
        {
            //Invalid - redisplay with errors
            return View(order);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. But `Address`is a `Model` and it has 
`public string AddressLine1 {get; set;}`. Now I want to replace `AddressLine1` to `Address`, what am I going to fill in there?

Comment: @TrungPham `Address` is of type `string` on that case as you can see in the [source code](https://mvcmusicstore.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#MvcMusicStore/Models/Order.cs) - If you are changing it to your own Model, then you will also need to edit the template in order to bring those into the form, and you will have to have a input of this type: `<input type="text" name="Address.AddressLine1" id="Address_AddressLine1" />` in order to be filled up automatically from your new Model.

Comment: `order.AccountNumber = User.Identity.Name;
order.OrderDate = DateTime.Now;
order.Address.AddressLine1 = values["AddressLine1"];
order.Address.AddressLine2 = values["AddressLine2"];
order.Address.City = values["City"];`. When I debugged, `User.Identity.Name` will display User Name, `OrderDate` is today and `Address` is an Address that User just typed. But it's `null` for `AddressLine` in this case. All I want to show the information passed through.

Comment: if you follow what I wrote in the comment, all be good, if you need code help, you do need to provide way more than what you have provided in your question, we need to see your class, and your view form.

Comment: I just updated my code, in `order.Address.AddressLine1` and `order.Address.AddressLine2` when I debugged it showed `order.Address` is **null**. Could you tell me what happened ?

Comment: @TrungPham you still missing the code for the View and the actually `order.Address` class... without them I can't provide you with any more help

Comment: I've updated the `View` and the `Address.cs` for more specific. @balexandre

Comment: @TrungPham answer updated with what are you doing wrong and how to update it - **Remember** you must do more changes if you want to continue and add to the database... This changes are the ones needed until you do `CreateOrder`.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm fixing now, I will let you know when I'm done. @balexandre

Comment: It's perfect! How do I do to save all the information in the `Order` in **Database**? Have I created a new **object**???

Comment: @TrungPham add that to a new question and drop the URL here... let's keep things in place for anyone that needs the same thing shall we? ;)

Comment: I just created a new question, will you please take a look at it? Here's the [link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22340448/asp-net-how-to-save-shipping-infors-into-adventureworks2012. Have a nice day! :)

Answer (score 1):

Try order.address = new address() before setting addressline1. You might have to resolve what type address is supposed to be.

Comment: I added it, but it still be `null`. `order.address = new address();` Did I miss something ???